# How can I loop a Firebase ML Recognize Text call until the correct text is returned?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

Like the title says, I want to loop a Firebase ML Recognize Text call until the correct text is returned. However, the problem I have is that Firebase ML Recognize Text call returns a promise that doesn't get resolved before the loop starts again. I've tried everything to make the call blocking and even implementing delay functions but nothing works.

Edit: I got it "working" with the following code.

```
fun test() {
    OpenSpotify().waitFor()
    firebaseReadText() // THE PROMISE IS IN HERE
    Thread.sleep(1)
    Timer().schedule(2) {
        if(text != "Example Text") {
            test()
        }
    }
}
```

Original example:

```
// Fetching media
val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE
        )

// Cursor for selecting photo
val cursor = applicationContext.contentResolver
            .query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                null, null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
            )

// Function for opening an app
val OpenSpotify: () -> Process = {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                arrayOf(
                    "su", "-c", "" +
                            "monkey -p com.spotify.music -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1" +
                            "screencap -p /sdcard/spotify.png"
                )
            )
}

// While loop
var text = ""
while (text != "Example Text?") {

    OpenSpotify().waitFor()
        if (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
            val imageLocation = cursor.getString(1)
            val imageFile = File(imageLocation)
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                val bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation)
                val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bm)
                val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer()
                detector.processImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { firebaseVisionText ->

                    Log.i("test", "test")
                    text = "Example Text?"
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.i("test", "Error with Firebase!")
                }
            }
        }
}
```